# Getting value of variable in another node. XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<foo1><xsl:variable name = "variable1">Value1</xsl:variable></foo1>
<foo2><xsl:value-of select="$variable1"/></foo2>
```

This does not work as it says variable1 is not defined or out of scope. How can I get the value of a variable in a different node within XSLT?

Comment: "How can I get the value of a variable in a different node within XSLT?" - you can't, all variables are lexically scoped in XSLT.  Tell us what problem you're actually trying to solve, with your input and required output XML and the XSLT you've tried so far, and we might be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: The way your example code is expressed, there is no benefit from having `variable1` declared within the `<foo1>` literal result element. If that's really the case, then just declare `variable1` before `<foo1>`, and then it will be in scope for `<foo2>` where you need it. If that's not the case, show us more detail so we can understand your constraints.